# Doctrine2 - using group by method to add totals for each month

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have the following table:

[image]

I require the SUM(total), SUM(cost), SUM(net) grouped as a total for each month.

So far I have the following queries:

**Returns a single global total:**

```
$qb ->add('select','SUM(u.total) as Total, Sum(u.cost) as Cost, Sum(u.net) as Net')
      ->where('u.status = :status')
      ->setParameter('status' , 1);
```

**Returns totals grouped by the created date:**

```
$qb ->add('select','SUM(u.total) as Total, Sum(u.cost) as Cost, Sum(u.net) as Net')
      ->groupBy('u.created')
      ->where('u.status = :status')
      ->setParameter('status' , 1);
```

How do I return by days or months or years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay looks like I solved this.

Doctrine query builder supports sub-string, so if a date looks like this:

```
2015-08-13 14:02:15
```

We can use substring to pull out the parts we want and then use the orderBy method to list by them.

Making listing by, day, hour, minute and second, simple.

This being the template:

```
$qb ->add('select','SUM(u.total) as Total, Sum(u.cost) as Cost, Sum(u.net) as Net, SUBSTRING(u.created, 6, 2) as Month')
            ->groupBy('Month')
            ->where('u.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('status' , 1);
```

Simply replace the SUBSTRING value with:

```
SUBSTRING(u.created, 1, 4) for Year
SUBSTRING(u.created, 6, 2) for Month
SUBSTRING(u.created, 9, 2) for Day
```

Day and Month will clearly run across multiple years and months respectively, so further checks would be required.

My code is like this if anyone is interested, I use multiple day, month and year attributes to ensure the data does not aggregate.

```
public function getSalesBy($date)
    {

        if (!in_array($date,['day','month','year']))
        {
            return [];
        }

        $qb = $this->ordersRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');

        if ($date == 'day')
        {
            $qb->add('select','SUM(u.total) as total, Sum(u.cost) as cost, Sum(u.net) as net, SUBSTRING(u.created, 9, 2) as day, SUBSTRING(u.created, 6, 2) as month, SUBSTRING(u.created, 1, 4) as year');
            $qb->groupBy('year,month,day');
        }

        if ($date == 'month')
        {
            $qb->add('select','SUM(u.total) as total, Sum(u.cost) as cost, Sum(u.net) as net, SUBSTRING(u.created, 9, 2) as day, SUBSTRING(u.created, 6, 2) as month, SUBSTRING(u.created, 1, 4) as year');
            $qb->groupBy('year,month');
        }

        if ($date == 'year')
        {
            $qb->add('select','SUM(u.total) as total, Sum(u.cost) as cost, Sum(u.net) as net, SUBSTRING(u.created, 9, 2) as day, SUBSTRING(u.created, 6, 2) as month, SUBSTRING(u.created, 1, 4) as year');
            $qb->groupBy('year');
        }

        $qb->where('u.status = :status')->setParameter('status' , 1);


        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    }
```